# Convert book with a right click from finder in OS X

Tags: macos, pdf, finder

Is there a way to convert documents / books (PDF, [DOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_%28computing%29), [Mobipocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobipocket), [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB), etc.) from one format to another, e.g. from DOC to PDF, by right clicking a file item?

The scenario I'm imagining is opening up finder, seeing a book, realize it's DOC and not Mobipocket so I can't drag it to my [Kindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle), right click it, go to some "convert to" menu item, and select Mobipocket from it.

Is there some software that adds this capability to the [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_%28software%29)?

Answer (score 4):

You could make this functionality yourself by combining [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) with [Automator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)) to make a service.  Services will show up in the menu when you right click on a file in the Finder.

One hint if you assemble this yourself is Calibre book conversion can be called from the command line.  Like so

```
/Applications/Calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert $1 ${1%.}.mobi
```

[This article](http://shinysparkly.com/blog/2011/03/02/create-an-online-ebook-converter-with-dropbox/) might help get you started if you decide to build this for yourself.  I am sorry I don't know of an application that does what you ask out of the box.